# Multitape Turing machines against single tape Turing machines

Tags: time-complexity, turing-machines, simulation, tape-complexity

*Introduction*: I recently learned that a multi-tape Turing Machine $\text{TM}_k$  is no more "powerful" than a single tape Turing machine $\text{TM}$. The proof that  $\text{TM}_k \equiv \text{TM}$ is based on the idea that a $\text{TM}$ can simulate a $\text{TM}_k$ by using a unique character to separate the respective areas of each of the $k$ tapes.

Given this idea, how would we prove that a process taking $t(n)$ time on a $\text{TM}_k$ can be simulated by a 2-tape Turing machine $\text{TM}_2$ with $ O(t(n))\log(t(n))$ time?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look at the original paper by Hennie and Stearns:

[F.C. Hennie and R.E. Stearns, "Two-Tape Simulation of Multitape Turing Machines"](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/viola/classes/papers/HennieStearns66.pdf), Journal of the ACM (JACM), Volume 13 Issue 4, Oct. 1966, pp. 533-546

The construction is a little bit elaborate, but not extremely difficult to understand. The basic idea is to store and keep the current symbol of each tape in the same fixed column (*home column*) and simulate a shift of the $k$ tapes using a series of partially filled "buffers" of increasing length placed on the two tapes on the left and right side of the home column in order to avoid a full shift (that would require $O(t(n)^2)$ steps). If you need further help, modify the question and ask about the points in the paper that are not clear.

Comment: Basically the trick in the construction is to buffer updates to the tape in a clever way. This has the effect that you have to update far away portions of the tape only when you have enough changes to carry out and it pays off.